# Transfer matrices - drift distances

Tags: optics

I have a question regarding transfer matrices in optics. For thin lenses, the thickness of the lense is not taken into the calculation because it is very small compared to the dimensions of the rest of the system.

Now let's say I have a lens like this one (just a thicker lens):

[image]

The thickness of the lens does now play a bigger role, but the length of the drift cannot be determined, because it depends on the beam. It might be close to 0, or could even be equal to the full thickness of the lens. This makes a difference of course. But how do I treat such a lens? Do I ignore the drift distance, and just calculate it as a thin lense?

Comment: does nobody have an idea on that?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it depends on your application. If the beam is small compared to the clear aperture of the lens, then you can probably treat it as a thin lens without any trouble.

If the beam is large, you will probably have to treat the rays differently depending on their distance from the optical axis. IIRC you won't be able to use a transfer matrix for that.

In the end, it all depends on why you need to calculate it, and how much accuracy you need.

Comment: thanks for your opinion! I need to calculate it, well, because I am a student and my professor wants us to do this in a test...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two surfaces are still spherical, you can still use transfer matrices to treat a thick lens.  Citing [the Wikipedia article on transfer matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis), the transfer matrix for a curved interface is

$$
I_C(n_i,n_f,R) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\\frac{n_i-n_f}{n_f R}&\frac{n_i}{n_f}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The ray matrix for translation is, as usual, 
$$
T(d) = \begin{pmatrix}1&d\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So, if your initial medium is vacuum ($n_i=1$), the index of refraction of your lens material is $n$, the thickness of your lens is $t$, and the curvature of both sides is the same and is given by $R$, then the combined transfer matrix is 
$$
I_C(n,1,-R)T(t)I_c(1,n,R)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{(1-n)t}{nR}+1&\frac{t}{n}\\
  -\frac{(1-n)(2nR+t(1-n))}{nR^2}&\frac{(1-n)t}{nR}+1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Notice that if you take the thin lens limit of this transfer matrix ($t\rightarrow0$) and apply the lensmaker's equation, then you recover the thin lens transfer matrix.

Comment: I was thinking that would only work if $d$ was large compared with the difference in thickness due to the curvature of the lens; otherwise $d$ would not be constant in the distance from the optical axis, and so the transfer matrix would not work.

Comment: @ptomato I think you are correct that this won't capture the difference in optical path length due to the varying thickness of the lens.  But, if you are far enough from the axis that it plays an important role, then you are outside the paraxial approximation, and the whole ray matrix formalism breaks down.  So, to summarize, this technique works for lenses which are thick, but whose thickness does not vary appreciably over the size of the beam.  It will not work for ball/condenser lenses.  At that point you have to use numerical methods.